# Auto Generate Field Names from table PHP

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, field

There is a problem of automatically retrieving field names from a MySQL table. If possible could the name be placed in this format along with the dynamically created text box? :

The codes that I have created so far are located below:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";

$name = mysql_query("SELECT * from users");

$property = mysql_fetch_field($name);

$i = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM users");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while($i<mysql_num_fields($result))
    {
      $meta=mysql_fetch_field($name,$i);
      $new = $meta->name;
      echo "$new: <input type=\"text\" name=\"{$row['Field']}\" size=\"40\"   
      maxlength=\"256\" /><br>";
      $i++;
    }
}
}
?>
```

The Dynamically created text box (according to the number of columns from the table) are working fine but the field names cannot be generated! Can someone please give advice or help on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code below will get table columns and generate the list of inputs. In you code you have a lot of things that are useless. You do not need to `select * from users`...

Here is the code

```
<?php
include "db_connect.php";

//  This is not needed! Useless query that loads all the info from db
//$name = mysql_query("SELECT * from users");
//$i = 0;

//  Here you are getting columns information
$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM users");

if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

//  Scan through all the columns
while ($field = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {

    //  structure of $field looks like this
    /*
      object(stdClass)[1]
      public 'Field' => string 'id' (length=2)
      public 'Type' => string 'int(11)' (length=7)
      public 'Null' => string 'NO' (length=2)
      public 'Key' => string 'PRI' (length=3)
      public 'Default' => null
      public 'Extra' => string 'auto_increment' (length=14)
     */

    //
    echo "$field->Field: <input type=\"text\" name=\"$field->Field\" size=\"40\" maxlength=\"256\" /><br>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
<?php

include "db_connect.php";

$name = mysql_query("SELECT * from checkusers");

$property = mysql_fetch_field($name);

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM checkusers");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
    for ($i = 0; $i < mysql_num_fields($name); $i++)
    {
      $meta=mysql_field_name($name, $i);
      echo "$meta: <input type=\"text\" name=\"{$row['health_id']}\" size=\"40\" 
      maxlength=\"256\" /><br>";
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
<?php

include "database.php";

$id = mysql_query("SELECT * from info");

$property = mysql_fetch_field($id);

$i = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM info");
if (!$result) {
echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
exit;
}
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while($i<mysql_num_fields($result))
    {
      $meta=mysql_fetch_field($result,$i);
      $new = $meta->id;
      echo "$new: <input type=\"text\" id=\"{$row['Field']}\" size=\"40\"   
      maxlength=\"256\" /><br>";
      $i++;
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: try this one.. this is your code.. i think i fix it.. but i dont know how to use this one :)

Comment: How did you fix it? What did you change from the original code? From your answer it is not clear at all...

Comment: this the code i fix ..if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    while($i<mysql_num_fields($result))
    {
      $meta=mysql_fetch_field($result,$i);
      $new = $meta->id;